# How do I overcome "Permission Denial....obtain access using ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT or related APIs"?

Tags: react-native, react-native-firebase

I'm using [react-native-firebase](https://rnfirebase.io/) and [react-native-document-picker](https://github.com/Elyx0/react-native-document-picker) and I'm trying to follow the [face detection tutorial](https://rnfirebase.io/ml-vision/face-detection).

Currently getting the following error despite having read access through [PermissionsAndroid](https://reactnative.dev/docs/permissionsandroid):

`Permission Denial: reading com.android.provides.media.MediaDocumentsProvider uri [uri] from pid=4746, uid=10135 requires that you obtain access using ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT or related APIs`

I am able to display the selected image by the user on the screen but the react-native-firebase functions seems to not be able to have permission. The error happens at this call: `const faces = await vision().faceDetectorProcessImage(localPath);`.

Any suggestions on how to give the face detection function access or what am I doing wrong?

My AndroidManifest.xml file contains the following:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

Here is all the code in that component for reference:

```
import React, {useState} from 'react';
import { Button, Text, Image, PermissionsAndroid } from 'react-native';
import vision, { VisionFaceContourType } from '@react-native-firebase/ml-vision';
import DocumentPicker from 'react-native-document-picker';



async function processFaces(localPath) {

  console.log(localPath)
  const faces = await vision().faceDetectorProcessImage(localPath);
  console.log("Got faces")

  faces.forEach(face => {
    console.log('Head rotation on Y axis: ', face.headEulerAngleY);
    console.log('Head rotation on Z axis: ', face.headEulerAngleZ);

    console.log('Left eye open probability: ', face.leftEyeOpenProbability);
    console.log('Right eye open probability: ', face.rightEyeOpenProbability);
    console.log('Smiling probability: ', face.smilingProbability);

    face.faceContours.forEach(contour => {
      if (contour.type === VisionFaceContourType.FACE) {
        console.log('Face outline points: ', contour.points);
      }
    });
  });
}

async function pickFile () {
    // Pick a single file
    try {
        const res = await DocumentPicker.pick({
            type: [DocumentPicker.types.images],
        });
        console.log(
            res.uri,
            res.type, // mime type
            res.name,
            res.size
        );
        return res
    } catch (err) {
        if (DocumentPicker.isCancel(err)) {
        // User cancelled the picker, exit any dialogs or menus and move on
            console.log("User cancelled")
        } else {
            console.log("Error picking file or processing faces")
            throw err;
        }
    }
}

const requestPermission = async () => {
    try {
      const granted = await PermissionsAndroid.request(
        PermissionsAndroid.PERMISSIONS.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE,
        {
          title: "Files Permission",
          message:
            "App needs access to your files " +
            "so you can run face detection.",
          buttonNeutral: "Ask Me Later",
          buttonNegative: "Cancel",
          buttonPositive: "OK"
        }
      );
      if (granted === PermissionsAndroid.RESULTS.GRANTED) {
        console.log("We can now read files");
      } else {
        console.log("File read permission denied");
      }
      return granted
    } catch (err) {
      console.warn(err);
    }
  };

function FaceDetectionScreen ({navigation}) {
    const [image, setImage] = useState("");
    return (
        <>
            <Text>This is the Face detection screen.</Text>
            <Button title="Select Image to detect faces" onPress={async () => {
                const permission = await requestPermission();
                if (permission === PermissionsAndroid.RESULTS.GRANTED) {
                    const pickedImage = await pickFile();
                    const pickedImageUri = pickedImage.uri
                    setImage(pickedImageUri);
                    processFaces(pickedImageUri).then(() => console.log('Finished processing file.'));
                }
                }}/>
            <Image style={{flex: 1}} source={{ uri: image}}/>
        </>
    ); 
}

export default FaceDetectionScreen;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to [this comment on a github issue](https://github.com/invertase/react-native-firebase/issues/2558#issuecomment-534955902) I was able to update my code and get it to work by updating the first three lines of processFaces as:

```
async function processFaces(contentUri) {
  const stat = await RNFetchBlob.fs.stat(contentUri)
  const faces = await vision().faceDetectorProcessImage(stat.path);
```

after importing `import RNFetchBlob from 'rn-fetch-blob'`.

[rn-fetch-blob](https://github.com/joltup/rn-fetch-blob)

Answer (score 1):

If you add cache option in DocumentPicker.pick() you dont need use RNFetchBlob.

In my case, I used like this:

```
await DocumentPicker.pickSingle({
  presentationStyle: 'fullScreen',
  allowMultiSelection: false,
  copyTo: 'cachesDirectory',
})
  .then(async (data) => {
    await handleSetUpload(data)
  })
  .finally(() => {
    setLoading(false)
  })
```

using the cachesDirectory, in data return it was possible to use the `data.fileCopyUri`