# Permission Denial: opening provider com.android.providers.media.MediaDocumentsProvider React native

Tags: react-native, google-cloud-storage

I am trying to upload the file with Uri to google cloud storage from my device. Then I am getting the following error:

```
`Error: Permission Denial: opening provider com.android.providers.media.MediaDocumentsProvider from ProcessRecord{...} (pid=16294, uid=10169) requires that you obtain access using ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT or related APIs`.
```

Upload code:

```
    const handleFileTranslation = async () => {
    try{
      const fileContent = await RNFS.readFile("content://com.android.providers.media.documents/document/document%3A1000000036", 'base64');
      const binaryData = Buffer.from(fileContent, 'base64');
      const response = await axios.post('https://storage.googleapis.com/upload/storage/v1/b/Bucket_Name/o?uploadType=media&name=Hello%20World', binaryData, {
        headers: {'Authorization': 'Bearer: ${oauthToken}',
                  "Content-Type": "application/pdf",},
        responseType: 'json',
      });
      // console.log('File upload successfully', response.data);
    }catch(error){
      console.log("Error uploading", error);
    }
      
  };
```

Comment: Sounds like your app needs to approve access to ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT. Try adding an entry in AndroidManifest.xml: <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT"/>

Comment: Or at the very least, you need to work with the permission required for ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62134894/how-do-i-overcome-permission-denial-obtain-access-using-action-open-document